# MS Access Query error on data type mismatch

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hi I am querying a linked table (ms excel sheet), If i leave out the "`,"Waiting for Losing Communications Provider Validation"`" from the WHERE clause below, all works fine, however if i leave it as below i get "Data Type Mismatch in Criteria" error. This is very confusing as there are records in the excel sheet that fit that "Waiting for Losing Communications Provider Validation" and i have also made sure the field is being seen  as TEXT, so im at a loss...

Any help from anyone would be appreciated...

```
SELECT COUNT(LatestGamma.MainNumber) AS [Ports Complete],
  LatestGamma.LineType,
  LatestGamma.CPStatus,
  MonthName(MONTH(LatestGamma.ConfirmedPortingDate)) AS [MONTH],
  YEAR(LatestGamma.ConfirmedPortingDate)             AS [YEAR]
FROM LatestGamma
WHERE LatestGamma.CPStatus IN ("Port Accepted","Pre Port Test Call Failed",
    "Waiting for Date Change Validation","Waiting for Losing Communications 
     Provider Validation")
AND LatestGamma.OrderID     >77526
GROUP BY LatestGamma.LineType,
  LatestGamma.CPStatus,
  YEAR(LatestGamma.ConfirmedPortingDate),
  MonthName(MONTH(LatestGamma.ConfirmedPortingDate))
ORDER BY YEAR(LatestGamma.ConfirmedPortingDate),
  MonthName(MONTH(LatestGamma.ConfirmedPortingDate));
```

Comment: May be it is something because of the length of the field?

Comment: did cross my mind but the field shows as 255

Comment: Is that exactly how your SQL looks? If so, you have split a phrase, which may not help.

Comment: no that was edited by @Guneli for some reason